# gravar arquivos no banco de dados com ajax + jquery

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

Não estou conseguindo salvar dados no banco de dados mysql com ajax, alguém pode ajudar? Não da erro nem nada, só não salva.
PHP:

```
$serve = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$serve){ echo 'erro';}
$db = mysql_select_db('observatoriogaia', $serve);

if($_GET['acao']=='btnCadCadastra'){

 $nome = $_GET['nome'];
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 $senha = $_GET['senha'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha)
VALUES ('$nome','$email','$senha')";

$re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $server;
    $server = 'http://localhost/';

$(document).on("click", "#btnCadCadastra", function(evt)
{
        $nome = $('#idNome').val();
        $email = $('#idEmail').val();
        $senha = $('#idSenha').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: $server+"/conecta.php",
                        data: "nome="+$nome+"&acao=btnCadCadastra",
                        data: "email="+$email+"&acao=btnCadCadastra",
                        data: "senha="+$senha+"&acao=btnCadCadastra",
                        success: function(data) {
                            intel.xdk.notification.alert('Usuário cadastrado'); 
                        }
                    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left" id="page_72_85">
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_8 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                    <label class="narrow-control label-top-left" for="idNome">Nome de Usuário</label>
                    <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ex: Gabriel" type="text" id="idNome" name="nome">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_9 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                    <label class="narrow-control label-top-left" for="idEmail">Email:</label>
                    <input class="wide-control" placeholder="seuemail@..." type="email" id="idEmail" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_10 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                    <label class="narrow-control label-top-left" for="idSenha">Senha</label>
                    <input class="wide-control" placeholder="**********" type="password" id="idSenha">
                </div>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" class="uib-jqm-flex widget uib_w_11 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button_group" data-ver="0" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a class="widget uib_w_12" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" id="btnCadCancela">Cancelar</a><a class="widget uib_w_14" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0"
                    data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="check" id="btnCadCadastra">Cadastrar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Problema resolvido! Minha falta de atenção não me deixou ver que eu deveria importar o arquivo javascript depois de importar os plug-ins do JQuery Mobile, o que resultou em erro ou seja, a ação não estava sendo executada... Obrigado Pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que estás a formatar esses dados de maneira errada. Usa assim:

```
data: {
    acao: 'btnCadCadastra',
    nome: $nome,
    email: $email,
    senha: $senha
},
```

que o jQuery faz o resto, ou seja: colocar tudo numa *query string*.

Comment: fiz esta alteração e nada... pare que o botão não executa a ação, pois não acontece nada

Comment: @G.Vilela indo por partes: tens algum erro na consola? o que dá `var_dump($_GET);` no PHP? <- provavelmente tens de ver essa resposta dentro do ajax ou no dev-tools (F12)

Comment: novamente, nada... não acontece nada ao clicar no botão...

Comment: Resolvido: faltou um & após a primeira variável passada, exemplo:            data: "nome="+$nome+"&email=''email''&acao=btnCadCadastra"